# If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then $|A| < |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, measurable-sets

Why is this statement false? If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then $\forall x \in A, x \in B$ but since $A \ne B$ then $\exists x \in B, x\notin A$

This should mean that $|B| > |A|$, right?

Comment: The irrationals form a proper subset of the reals, but the two sets have the same size. Your statement is true for finite sets, however.

Comment: ahh I didn't think of infinite sets. thank you.

Comment: In fact, this is one possible way of *defining* infinite sets: "A set $B$ is infinite if and only if there exists a proper subset $A\subset B$, $A\neq B$, and a bijection $f\colon B\to A$."

Answer (score 0):

$|A|\le|B|$, and that corresponds to the fact that $A$ injects into $B$.